# No pagination when searching in mobile theme

Tags: bug, search, mobile-web, pagination

What the title says, there's simply no link to other pages when browsing the search results in all mobile sites:

> [image: s1]

I.e. these buttons are missing:

> [image: s2]

The above screenshots are of Google Chrome 46.0.2490.80 64-bit running on Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 64-bit, but I've tested on an Android and on an iOS device as well and it seems to be browser-agnostic.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Searching for "Ubuntu" on Ask Ubuntu (on the full site) yields ~217,288 results, yet searching for "Ubuntu" on the mobile version yields 15 results with no way to browse results past those. Not only on Ask Ubuntu, this is just for the sake of the example, it's the same on all mobile sites. I added a screenshot to clarify.

Comment: @Pat it's happening here on MSE as well, just click "mobile" in the footer, search for something, and see.

Comment: Now I see @kos. Thanks for clarifying.